# How to remove special character in the string

Tags: regex, character-encoding

This could be a possbile duplicate. Still im not able to find a solution for it.Yes i tried with regexp but is there any other way to solve it?

```
String s="This is a â¦sample â¦ Java class to show the issueâ¨\nHow to solve it?";

        try {
        System.out.print("ANSWER="+URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));  ;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can i fix this issue? Can some one help
Thanks in advance

The console output

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=17620, tid=14220
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_79-b15) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Comment: My guess is that the error is because of `\n` in the string, if that is the case, you can escape it by preceding backslash. If you're trying to remove those characters from string, you can use [`[^\w\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/oZ5vO7/1) and replace by empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String yourString= "This is a â¦sample â¦ Java class to show the issueâ¨\nHow to solve it?";
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(yourString);
          while(myMatcher.find())
          {
              String temp= myMatcher.group();
              yourString=yourString.replaceAll("\\"+temp, " ");
          }
System.out.println(yourString);
```